# What happens when you cancel preallocating on steam?

Tags: steam

I understand why it allocates the space. I am just wondering what specifically happens when you cancel mid preallocation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about pre-allocating space to install a game, cancelling this process cancels the download and installation process as well. This means your game won't be installed.

Any space already allocated will be returned to normal

Comment: But does it restore the file system back to before the pre-allocation began?

Comment: Yes, it does return the blocked storage space.